# Can I accept Git pull requests out of order?

Tags: git, github

When reviewing a few pull requests I accidentally accepted a request that was submitted a year after another pull request that remains unaccepted. I haven't reviewed the code just yet, but out of curiosity what happens if I accept pull requests out of order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing intrinsically matters by days, it gets merged as pull requests get accepted. So if the next one you accept has major conflicts you won't be able to merge until they're resolved.